# Como generar campos auto calculables?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Buenas estoy intentando hacer que en un campo se calcule automaticamente el monto del descuento, porque hasta el momento lo completaba manualmente mediante inputs.

Ahora realicé esta lógica que nose si esta bien en mi controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    /*dd($request->all());*/
    $presupuestoProducto = new PresupuestoProducto();

    $presupuestoProducto->presupuesto_id = $request->presupuesto_id;
    
    $presupuestoProducto->sale_price = $request->sale_price;
    
    $presupuestoProducto->discount_percentage = $request->discount_percentage;
    $presupuestoProducto->discount = ($sale_price * $discount_percentage)/100;
    
    $presupuestoProducto->save();
    Session::flash('success');
    return redirect()->route('presupuestos-productos.view');
}
```

No se si esto esta bien hecho y no se como probar si funciona, porque tampoco se como hacer para que automaticamente aparezca automaticamente el valor del resultado de esa formula para calcular el descuento.

Hasta ahora mi vista es asi:

```
                  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label for="sale_price">Precio de Venta</label>
                        <input type="number"  pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?" step="00.01" name="sale_price" class="form-control">
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="discount_percentage">Porcentaje de descuento (%)</label>
                        <input type="number" name="discount_percentage" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="discount">Descuento</label>
                        <input type="number" name="discount" class="form-control">
                    </div>
```

Como puedo hacer para que ese ultimo campo discount no sea un input y aparezca en un textbox el resultado calculado en mi controller?

Comment: Me temo que tendrás que usar JavaScript para eso, o incluso puedes usar Livewire.